# Node.js cloud hosts with Windows support

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloud-hosting

I've researched many node.js cloud hosts, yet I'm having trouble finding one that suits my needs. The host needs to have free service for as long as an application is in development (sandbox mode). It also needs to have a Windows client, and ease of use is a huge plus. If possible, I'd like the host to be out of beta.

Can anyone recommend a simple node.js host that meets my needs?

Comment: What does "Windows client" for a host mean to you? Wouldn't most people on Windows just use WinSCP or `pscp` to transfer their files?

Comment: Services like dotCloud require Linux or OSX for their CLIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out Azure hosting?

> The host needs to have free service for as long as an application is in development (sandbox mode)

They're currently offering a [90-day free trial](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/) and they've spent some real effort making [Node.js work with their platform](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/).

> It also needs to have a Windows client, and ease of use is a huge plus.

They have a socket.io example and an example of using their free Windows-based dev tools to get up and running.

> If possible, I'd like the host to be out of beta.

Node.JS has yet to hit version 1.0. At some level the whole tool chain is beta. However, Windows Azure is paid for and supported. They have people actively working on both Node.JS and some drivers (*such as SQL Server support*). To me, that's as "non-beta" as you'll get right now.